# Calling Azure face detect api from NodeJs with binary image data coming from Postman client

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am trying to build a REST middle-ware in nodejs which will call azure face api's, like the picture shown below. [image]

When I call my node js endpoint for face detection with required data and an image file then the I successfully receive the request and the binary data of the image in request.body.

Since I received the request in my middle-ware  now I am supposed to call Azure face detection end point with the received data from my node js middle-ware.
[now here is the problem]

//---------------call made from node js to azure face detection api----

```
Request.post({
    "headers": {
      "content-type": reqBinaryContentType,     
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": azureSubscriptionKey,     
      'Content-Length': req.headers['content-length']
    },  

      "body":req.body,
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {     
      return console.dir(error);
    }   
    res.send(JSON.parse(body))
  })
```

//---------------

Error:
`{"error":{"code":"InvalidImageSize","message":"Image size is too small."}}`

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how big the image file is? From the [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) the image file must be from 1KB to 4MB.

Comment: Hi Jon, Images are in the range of 5-10 KB and each image has a wider face in it. I have used same image/s in postman client and hit the Azure rest api end points directly and got the expected results. its just that when I send same postman request to my node js middle-ware I get this error. Primary reason that I suspect is receiving Binary data from my incoming request and assigning it new request that I am making to azure face api.